# Spring cloud config properties not honouring config properties

Tags: spring-cloud, consul, spring-cloud-config

I wish to use consul strictly as a config source.
I am using `spring-cloud-consul-config` to get my config.
I am using [git2consul](https://github.com/Cimpress-MCP/docker-git2consul) to load files into consul and read them. 
As per the [spring cloud documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-consul/1.2.1.RELEASE/) I have added the following to my **build.gradle**

```
compile ("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-config")
```

and have the following in my **application.properties**

```
spring.application.name=test-service
spring.cloud.consul.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.consul.enabled=true
spring.cloud.consul.config.format=FILES
```

The problem I am facing is that the expected properties are not being loaded into the ConfigurationProperties beans. On further debugging in the [ConsulPropertySourceLocator::locate(Environment environment)](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/spring-cloud-consul-config/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/consul/config/ConsulPropertySourceLocator.java#L122) method, I see that the **this.properties** object is still loaded with **KEY_VALUE** enum.

This led me to [ConsulConfigBootstrapConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/spring-cloud-consul-config/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/consul/config/ConsulConfigBootstrapConfiguration.java) class, where the ConsulConfigProperties bean is being instantiated using a constructor.

Is this the problem or do I have something wrong in my setup. 
If someone has a working setup of git2consul and spring cloud config, please can you point me to it for reference.

Comment: What version are you using? What is in `/config`?

Comment: spring cloud version: 1.2.1-RELEASE 
my /config folder in consul has a folder test-service which contains application.properties and test-service.properties. These files are also present in the config folder.

Comment: They should only be needed in `/config`. What does the `/env` actuator endpoint say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These values that you have in `application.properties`

```
spring.application.name=test-service
spring.cloud.consul.config.enabled=true
spring.cloud.consul.enabled=true
spring.cloud.consul.config.format=FILES
```

need to be in [`bootstrap.properties`](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR1/#_customizing).